# Newly (re)installed Windows 7 fails to boot: WINLOAD.EXE could not be loaded

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot

I did a clean install on my Windows 7 Acer laptop. The installation seemed to go all right, but it shows this error:

> **Windows Boot Manager**
>   
>     Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause. To fix the problem:
>
> 1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer.
> 2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
> 3. Click "repair your computer."
>
> If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer manufacturer for assistance.
>
> File: \windows\system32\winload.exe
>
> Status: 0xc0000001
>
> Info: The selected entry could not be loaded because the application is missing or corrupt.

I have tried startup repair, which isn’t working.

Also another method, but you have to have 'bytes' in your registry. My `RegBack` file has 0 bytes. Is that a cause for concern? I’m not sure what to do; could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: stackoverflow is related to programming - your question is not.

Comment: This is batch. Or CMD or whatever. I just need help with it. Please..

Comment: What does "isn't working" mean? That the disc didn't load, there was an error else where?

Answer (score -1):

Your case is unique. To resolve uncommon problems with windows installation, usually i gonna format the drive.

Take a look at this link:
https://www.wikihow.com/Install-Windows-7-(Beginners)

There are many pictures, and later at some points, it has some picture with words:
**disk 0 unallocated space**

To remove partition 0, partition 1... partition n, you need to format the drive. make sure you see
**disk 0 unallocated space**

Install in unallocated space, not on previous partition.